# Logging with hug and waitress

Tags: python, logging, wsgi, waitress, hug

I want to add logging to my Python [hug](http://www.hug.rest) REST app. I couldn't find any wayto do it when serving the app through the `hug` command (via `hug -f app.py`), therefore I try to combine hug with [waitress](https://github.com/Pylons/waitress/).

My minimal app structure in the file `app.py` looks like:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
import hug
.
.
.
@hug.get()
def func(detail):
    logger.debug("debug func")
    .
    .
    .
```

And I serve this with a waitress script `run.py`:

```
import logging
import waitress

import app

logger = logging.getLogger('waitress')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.debug("logger set to DEBUG")

waitress.serve(app.__hug_wsgi__)
```

When I execute  `python run.py` in a console, the app spins up nicely and the results of `func` are served back, however the debug messages from inside func ("debug func") *and* from `run.py` ("logger set to DEBUG") I cannot see in the console.

What is going wrong and how can I fix it? (I'm happy to use another (Windows-capable) WSGI server if that's easier.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to configure logging for the `logging` module. Take a look at the [documentation for `logging.config`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html) (in particular `dictConfig` and `fileConfig`). As a start, to test whether it works, you can simply call

```
logging.basicConfig()
```

in `app.py` before you do any logging. This will make the output of all channels go to `sys.stderr`.

Don't forget to do `logging.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)` in `app.py` too if you want the debug message there to be visible.

Comment: That's it. Thanks.